# is Magento Mobile still officially supported?

Tags: mobile, mage-xmlconnect

Looks like all the Magento Mobile related documents are very old already, is it still officially supported by Magento now? do we have any newer support documentation?

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/categories/category/magento-mobile/

I tried in admin,  admin --> mobile - manage Apps --> Save and Submit App, it doesn't have any response, is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Prior to the release of magento `1.9.0.1`, In magento community addition release there was a menu for mobile app (mobile theme) management.

but after the `1.9.0.1` release magento has introduce the responsive theme which is also mobile friendly so there is no need to have the old mobile app management thing, so in the recent updates of magento they have removed the mobile menu.